# 2 JavaScript Functions Not Working When Used Together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small `popover` window that I call with this function:

```
$('.pop').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
        $('#hidden-input').val(this.id);
        return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
});
```

I have another JS function that validates checkbox selection making sure at least one has been selected

```
// required checkboxes
var requiredCheckboxes = $("#car").find(':checkbox[required]');

requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){
    if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
        requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
    }
    else {
        requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
    }
});
```

Both are working correctly until I use the checkbox function inside the `popover` window.

Any solutions to combine these two?

Edit:

html:

```
<!-- Popup select table -->
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">
    Select Animal  
</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <form method="post" id="car">
<fieldset>
    <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Cat" required/>Cats
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Dog" required />Dogs<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Bird" required />Birds<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit now" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not look like HTML

Comment: The HTML has been posted in my OP

Answer (score 0):

Put your checkbox validation function to popover callback.

```
$('.pop').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
        $('#hidden-input').val(this.id);
        return $("#popover-content").html();
    },
    callback: function(){
    // validation codes
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but with no luck and the checkbox  function is still asking me to check all boxes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that no checkboxes exist when that second code segment is run.

Rather delegate your change listener to the body:

```
$("body").on('change', '#cars :checkbox[required]', function() { ... });
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution but I must be doing something wrong as the popover wont even open. Can you post the full code?

Comment: The change listener shouldn't affect the popover at all. Take a look at jQuery's docs for .on (http://api.jquery.com/on/). I can post more detail later.

Comment: I do appreciate your help, I did have some missing brackets and got the popover working, however the validation is still asking me to check all all checkboxes. Any ideas?